# Java POI - read date from Excel file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to read the date (yyyy-MM-dd) in Java POI.

```
Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

switch(cell.getCellType()){
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
         if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){  [ERROR HERE]
              System.out.print(cell.getDateCellValue() + "\t\t");
         }else{
              System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
         }
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
        break;
}
```

However, I get the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:882)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getNumericCellValue(XSSFCell.java:220)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(DateUtil.java:495)
at others.ReadDateTime.main(ReadDateTime.java:44)
Java Result: 1
```

How should I corrected it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dates cannot be stored in `CELL_TYPE_STRING` cell. You should store it in `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` cell. See [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getDateCellValue()) for details.

You also missed `break` keyword after first `case`. So if cell is `Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING` then also

```
System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
```

is called.

So it should be:

```
switch(cell.getCellType()) {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            System.out.print(dateFormat.format(cell.getDateCellValue()) + "\t\t");
        } else {
            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
        }
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
        break;
}
```

Comment: From the above code, the output is shown as integer. How to make a date format like (dd-mm-YYYY)?

Comment: @MichaelKuan Be also aware that `mm` in format means minutes while  `MM` means months.

Comment: Ok. I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is direct pick from [Apache POI tutorial](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html), you make like to visit and get more details.

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                        System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                    System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println();
            }
```

Formatting date: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509017/get-date-from-excel-sheet-using-poi) thread may answer your follow up question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Date date = row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue(); //Get Date
cell.getDateCellValue(); //Get date time
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

Hope is help.

Answer (score 0):

After getting date from cell

```
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                break;
```

Then simply format the date like this:

```
Date mydate=cell.getDateCellValue();
                            SimpleDateFormat fo= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                            System.out.println(fo.format(mydate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;

// ...

Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC || cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA) {
    String cellValue = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();
        cellValue = df.format(date);
    }
    System.out.println(cellValue);
}
```